# Using my sensor values, what are relevant data analysis techniques?

Tags: algorithms

I am currently trying to devise a system using gyroscope+accelerometers placed in on a hat/cap in certain areas of the head (Front-left, Front-right, Centre, Back-left, Back-right). I want to create a system that can determine if the hat is roughly worn incorrectly (ie misaligned, tilted to the side, backwards).

The experiment is to:

- measure sensor values(angles) when the hat is correctly worn and not
  in motion (rest)
- measure sensor values(angles) when the hat is correctly worn and
  in motion (nodding up and down, side-to-side)
- measure sensor values(angles) when the hat is Incorrectly worn in
  both not in motion and in motion.

I am asking is theres a suitable data analysis algorithm/technique to use these sensor values and essentially give a rough estimate if the hat is worn correctly or not.